# How to get all IDBIndex key values (instead of object store primary keys)?

Tags: indexeddb

I have an IndexedDB object store with a primary key and an additional index (with a unique key constraint).

Now I want to retrieve all key values of this index.

Previously, I used IDBIndex.getAllKeys(), but appearently the behaviour of this method has changed to return the object store primary keys instead of the index keys.
(I cannot, however, find any documentation, or reference in browser release notes to that effect...)

So my question is:
What is the recommended, most performant way to retrieve all index key values?

Comment: Have you tried IDBIndex.prototype.getAll?

Comment: Yes, I have:
IDBIndex.prototype.getAll return the entire objects from the store (which in my case is quite a lot of data and takes 1500ms+)


IDBIndex.prototype.getAllKeys on the other hand returns only the key values in <200ms and, of course, a fraction of the memory footprint...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IDBIndex.getAll` will work, but it will read all the values into memory which may be slow.

And you are correct that `IDBIndex.getAllKeys` returns only the primary keys, not the index keys.

Unfortunately there is no similar single function that will return the index keys, but you can use `IDBIndex.openKeyCursor` and avoid reading the values into memory:

```
const result = [];

index.openKeyCursor().onsuccess = (event) => {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
        // cursor.key is the index key, cursor.primaryKey is the primary key,
        // and cursor.value is undefined because we're using openKeyCursor
        // rather than openCursor.
        result.push(cursor.key);
        cursor.continue();
    } else {
        cb(result);
    }
};
```

I haven't benchmarked this, but in theory it could be close to as fast as `getAllKeys`, although probably at least somewhat slower because it requires N events to be fired and handled rather than one.

Just don't try it in MS Edge :)

> Previously, I used IDBIndex.getAllKeys(), but appearently the behaviour of this method has changed to return the object store primary keys instead of the index keys. (I cannot, however, find any documentation, or reference in browser release notes to that effect...)

If you were using [indexeddb-getall-shim](https://github.com/dumbmatter/IndexedDB-getAll-shim), an earlier version did erroneously return the index keys rather than the primary keys. That was never in the spec, just a bug in the shim. Since I wrote the shim... my apologies if this is indeed the source of your confusion!

Comment: I don't use the getall-shim, but the [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) lib instead. Maybe something changed there, I'm not sure...
Regardless;
Do you know why there is an `IDBIndex.getAllKeys()` method if it returns the same thing als `IDBObjectStore.getAlllKeys()` ?
If this maybe an oversight in the spec and `IDBIndex.getAllKeys()` should actually return the index's keys instead of the primary keys?

Comment: I'm not sure why they did it that way... I can imagine wanting to get the primary keys, but I can also imagine wanting to get the index keys. https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/71 asks the same question.

Answer (score 4):

> Do you know why there is an `IDBIndex.getAllKeys()` method if it returns the same thing as `IDBObjectStore.getAllKeys()`

One reason for having these two separate methods is that they both accept an optional `query` argument, which is a key range.

In the case of `IDBObjectStore.getAllKeys(query)`, the key range is a range of *primary keys*, and result is an array of *primary keys*

In the case of `IDBIndex.getAllKeys(query)`, the key range is a range of *index keys*, and result is an array of *primary keys*

Example:

```
/* store (key = SSN) */
const users = await db.createObjectStore("users", { keyPath: "SSN" });

/* index (key = surname) */
users.createIndex("surname", "surname");

/* 1. get all SSNs from store */
const keys = await users.getAllKeys();

/* 2. get all SSNs starting between 'a' and 'f' */
const keys = await users.getAllKeys(IDBKeyRange.bound('a', 'f'));

/* 3. get all SSNs from index (same as #1) */
const keys = await users.index("surname").getAllKeys();

/* 4. get all SSNs where surname is between 'a' and 'f' (different to #2) */
const keys = await users.index("surname").getAllKeys(IDBKeyRange.bound('a', 'f'));
```